# Counting rows with start date before AND end date after in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with an unique id column, start date column and end date column:

```
ID | start date | end date
```

I want to count the rows (or id's) with a start date BEFORE 01-01-2020 AND and end date which is AFTER 01-01-2020 OR empty.

All dates are in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: [This](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-between-dates) was found in a quick google search and is a good start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way:

Added two columns named 'Start Year' and 'End Year' with the following formula:

```
=IF(B1;YEAR(B1);"")
```

With the B column the start date column and for end year it references the end date
column of course. This returns the year and if the cell is empty it returns empty.

Then I used pivot tables. Not a direct solution but it works and it is not too complicated.